# How to change this Access TRANSFORM statement to Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I need to convert this Access query to Sql Server but it looks like Transform and Pivot are not valid Sql Server functions. What is the equivalent function? Or would I have to rework the entire query all together?

```
TRANSFORM Sum([Rates by Quarter and Bedsize].[State CLABSI Rate]) AS [SumOfState CLABSI Rate]
SELECT [Rates by Quarter and Bedsize].Bedsize
FROM [Rates by Quarter and Bedsize]
GROUP BY [Rates by Quarter and Bedsize].SizeCategory, [Rates by Quarter and Bedsize].Bedsize
ORDER BY [Rates by Quarter and Bedsize].SizeCategory
PIVOT [Rates by Quarter and Bedsize].SummaryYQ;
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done from version 2005 onwards in SQL server, check out this link, to answer your question; yes you will need to re-write this query as the MS Access syntax will not be compatible.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx